# corrupt syslog due to crash?

Tags: crash, syslog

I have corrupt syslog here

[syslog](https://paste.ee/p/cRYcG#section0)

with binary characters at

Oct 19 15:51:18

Could this be due to a system crash? My screen was black when I arrived.

Comment: Yes, it could be due to a system crash. You might observe similar in your `/var/log/kern.log` file. I usually just edit out the problem area, or if using grep to find stuff, allow treating binary files as text.

Comment: OK, thanks will remove this post, because pasted file will expire in one year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the crash makes the text file look like binary file, use `grep` and answer from this question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/328101/how-do-i-grep-through-binary-files-that-look-like-text